# Set Top Padding affects Bottom Margin of a View

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

This is bottom margin:

```
@Override
protected void directionDownScrolling(View recyclerView) {
    MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0,
            (int) recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_recycler_view_spacing));
    mHandler.postDelayed(() -> recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params), 250);
}
```

And Top Padding :

```
@Override
protected void directionDownScrolling(View recyclerView) {
    // Calculate ActionBar height
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    int actionBarHeight = recyclerView.getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true) ?
            TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()) :
            (int) recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_recycler_view_spacing);
    recyclerView.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);
}
```

As you see top padding applies without no delay, but I expect bottom margin appears after 250ms,

but as soon as top padding applies, bottom margin appears as well. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: 250ms is a very short time to distinguish I think. Did you try with a larger amount of time here and check if the same thing happens?

Comment: Yes as soon as padding applies, bottom margin appears as well. if I set 250ms delay for padding then it will work as expected, but why? what is the relation?

Comment: I am still confused. Did you put 10 seconds delay and check if that works? 10 seconds will be 10000 in millis I think. Please try with that instead of 250 and report back here.

Comment: It appears without no delay even if I set 10sec. You can clone the project and try : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/tree/quick_hide_behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the layout parameters from `recyclerView`:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
```

Then you setup the margins directly on it:

```
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0,
        (int) recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_recycler_view_spacing));
```

So the delayed message doesn't do anything:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(() -> recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params), 250);
```

This would make a difference if you'd set the layout params to some other instance. Instead call `setMargins` delayed:

```
@Override
protected void directionDownScrolling(View recyclerView) {
    MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
    int marginBottom = (int) recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_recycler_view_spacing));
    mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, marginBottom);
            recyclerView.requestLayout();
    }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Strange for me is if I set 250ms delay for top padding : 'recyclerView.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);' it works as expected. What is the reason of that?

Comment: The layout is triggered when you set the padding. As the margins are already setup, they are applied as well. I added a call to `requestLayout()` in my example.